# Payload Syntax for batchUpdate

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am using the `googleapis` module in a Node application. I was using version 21 but have just updated to version 52 due to a security vulnerability in the older version.

There are several breaking changes. I have overcome most except for formatting a date/time string. Is the following payload correct for formatting a date/time value in cell A11?

```
const formatDate = (next) => {
  sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    auth: authClient,
    spreadsheetId: sheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [{
        "repeatCell": {
          range: { sheetId: 0, startRowIndex: 10, endRowIndex: 11, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: 1},
          cell: { userEnteredFormat: { numberFormat: { "type": "DATE_TIME", "pattern": "ddd yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" } } },
          fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
          }
        }]
    }
  }, (err, response) => {
      // ...
      next();
     }
  );
}
```

No errors were returned with the above payload, but the formatting is not taking place. Is the key `requestBody`? Previously I was using `resource`.

I used `async` to perform authentication before formatting the date:

```
const authClient = new google.auth.JWT(client_email, null, private_key, SCOPES, null);
const sheetId = "1vgiEnV8fU_MrnIy31fbPAzhHz.......";

function authenticate(next) {
  authClient.authorize((err) => {
     next(err);
  }
}
const tasks = [ authenticate, insertRow, formatdate ];
require("async").series(tasks);
```

Code for `insertRow` is not included here, but that works without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your script is correct. The cell format of "A11" is modified with the request body. And in this case, the request body can be used for both `requestBody` and `resource`.

But please confirm the following points, again.

- `sheetId` of `spreadsheetId: sheetId,` is required to be the Spreadsheet ID.
- In this case, when `=now()` is put to the cell "A11" and run the script, you can see the modified cell format.
- By the following modification, you can check the returned values from Sheets API.

  ```
    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
      {
        auth: authClient,
        spreadsheetId: "spreadsheetId",  // <--- Please check this.
        requestBody: {
          requests: [
            {
              repeatCell: {
                range: {
                  sheetId: 0,
                  startRowIndex: 10,
                  endRowIndex: 11,
                  startColumnIndex: 0,
                  endColumnIndex: 1,
                },
                cell: {
                  userEnteredFormat: {
                    numberFormat: {
                      type: "DATE_TIME",
                      pattern: "ddd yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm",
                    },
                  },
                },
                fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(res.data);
      }
    );
  ```

#### Note:

- In my environment, I tested your script with `googleapis@52.1.0`, and I could confirm the script worked.
- This modified script supposes that your authorization process for using Sheets API has already been done.

#### References:

- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

### Added:

#### Sample script for testing:

```
const client_email = "###";  // Please set here.
const private_key = "###";  // Please set here.
const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set here.

const { google } = require("googleapis");
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  client_email,
  null,
  private_key,
  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
);
jwtClient.authorize((err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: jwtClient });
sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
  {
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          repeatCell: {
            range: {
              sheetId: 0,
              startRowIndex: 10,
              endRowIndex: 11,
              startColumnIndex: 0,
              endColumnIndex: 1,
            },
            cell: {
              userEnteredFormat: {
                numberFormat: {
                  type: "DATE_TIME",
                  pattern: "ddd yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm",
                },
              },
            },
            fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.data);
  }
);
```

Comment: I set `includeSpreadsheetInResponse` to `true` and I can see the correct title of the spreadsheet I am working on in `data.updatedSpreadsheet` in the response. So `spreadsheetId` and authentication should be correct. I will like to inspect the response in more detail to troubleshoot. What is the syntax for `responseRanges` in the request? I tried `A11` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Old Geezer Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I could understand that in your script, `sheetId` is the Spreadsheet ID which is not the sheet ID. About your request body, I think that your request body is correct. Because in my environment, when I tested your request body, I could confirm that the format of cell "A11" of `sheetId: 0` was changed to the pattern `ddd yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your whole script without your personal information? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Old Geezer By the way, about `What is the syntax for responseRanges in the request?`, the official document says `Limits the ranges included in the response spreadsheet. Meaningful only if includeSpreadsheetInResponse is 'true'.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) In your case, for example, it seems that when `"responseRanges": ["Sheet1"],` is used, the response from Sheet1 is retrieved. But in this case, it might be suitable to use the method Method: spreadsheets.get.

Comment: thanks for helping. I have updated the question with more code. It is the same as your example. In `spreadSheetId` I am using an id with value like 1VzMvq5G6jO3vSHJMRBQAI,,,,,, the part you find in the Drive url, and not the "tab" id as in `range.sheetId`. Just before `updateBatch` I was performing an `append` operation. That works fine and it would mean that authentication should be working, no? I use the Node `async` module to line up the tasks to be executed in sequence synchronously.

Comment: @Old Geezer Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I could confirm that you are requesting Sheets API using the service account. From this situation, can you confirm whether the Spreadsheet you check is shared with the service account, again? When the Spreadsheet is shared with the email of service account, you can directly check the updated Spreadsheet using the browser. How about this?

Comment: @Old Geezer And, in your script, `sheetId: 0` is used. In this case, the request body is used to the 1st sheet in the Spreadsheet when the Spreadsheet is created. I'm worry whether you check other sheet. And also, in order to test the modified cell format, you can check it by putting `=NOW()` to the cell "A11".

Comment: If the Spreadsheet is created by the service account, please share it with your Google account. By this, you can see it at the browser.

Comment: I am viewing the spreadsheet in realtime in Chrome as I am stepping through the code, so yes I am getting feedback right away. The insert step performed nicely, so access permissions should be taken care of. It is just that the formatting is not having effect. The spreadsheet was created by a human, but granted write rights to the service account. (I have updated the code in my question to make it more complete.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216919/discussion-between-old-geezer-and-tanaike).